# Error in the administration menu does not open in the first click

Tags: jquery

I'm working on my administration panel.

My menu must always be closed, if the user wants to see more detail or more clearly the menu must click on the green button so that the menu expands.

But I have problems in the menu, I have to click twice on the green button so that the menu expands.

Can you explain how I correct the errors in the administarcion menu?

```js
var toggle = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".page-container").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed-back").addClass("sidebar-collapsed");
});

$(".sidebar-icon").click(function() {
  if (toggle) {
    $(".page-container").addClass("sidebar-collapsed").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
    $("#menu span").css({
      "position": "absolute"
    });
  } else {
    $(".page-container").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#menu span").css({
        "position": "relative"
      });
    }, 400);
  }
  toggle = !toggle;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/28-03-2016/shoppy/web/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/28-03-2016/shoppy/web/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/28-03-2016/shoppy/web/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-container sidebar-collapsed">
  <div class="left-content">
    <div class="mother-grid-inner">
      <!--header start here-->

      <!--heder end here-->
      <!-- /script-for sticky-nav -->
      <!--inner block start here-->
      <div class="inner-block">
        <!--market updates updates-->
        <div class="market-updates">
          <div class="col-md-4 market-update-gd">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 market-update-gd">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 market-update-gd">

          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
        <!--market updates end here-->
        <!---728x90--->
        <div style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;margin-top: 5px;"></div>
        <!--mainpage chit-chating-->
        <div class="chit-chat-layer1">
          <div class="col-md-6 chit-chat-layer1-left">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 chit-chat-layer1-rit">

          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
        <!--main page chit chating end here-->
        <!---728x90--->

        <!--main page chart start here-->
        <div class="main-page-charts">
          <div class="main-page-chart-layer1">
            <div class="col-md-6 chart-layer1-left">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 chart-layer1-right">
              <div class="user-marorm">


              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--main page chart layer2-->
        <div class="chart-layer-2">

          <div class="col-md-6 chart-layer2-right">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 chart-layer2-left">

          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>

        <!--climate start here-->
        <div class="climate">


          <div class="col-md-4 climate-grids">

          </div>

        </div>
        <!--climate end here-->
      </div>
      <!--inner block end here-->
      <!---728x90--->
      <!--COPY rights end here-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--slider menu-->
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-icon"> <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> </a>
      <a href="#"> <span id="logo"></span>
        <!--<img id="logo" src="" alt="Logo"/>-->
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li id="menu-home"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Dashboard</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Components</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="grids.html">Grids</a></li>
            <li><a href="portlet.html">Portlets</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-comunicacao"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book nav_icon"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Element</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-comunicacao-sub">
            <li id="menu-mensagens" style="width: 120px"><a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-arquivos"><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
            <li id="menu-arquivos"><a href="icons.html">Icons</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="maps.html"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Maps</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-academico"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Pages</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-academico-sub">
            <li id="menu-academico-boletim"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
            <li id="menu-academico-avaliacoes"><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="charts.html"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Charts</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Mailbox</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-academico-sub">
            <li id="menu-academico-avaliacoes"><a href="inbox.html">Inbox</a></li>
            <li id="menu-academico-boletim"><a href="inbox-details.html">Compose email</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span style="position: absolute;">System</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-academico-sub">
            <li id="menu-academico-avaliacoes"><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
            <li id="menu-academico-boletim"><a href="blank.html">Blank</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span style="position: absolute;">E-Commerce</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-academico-sub">
            <li id="menu-academico-avaliacoes"><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
            <li id="menu-academico-boletim"><a href="price.html">Price</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Becuase `toggle` starts as `true`, it will fall into the first block of your `if`, which is trying to *expand* the menu. You should really change `toggle` to be something more descriptive, like `menuIsHidden`.

Comment: @TylerRoper I would not know how to explain to you I am working with the following [template](https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/28-03-2016/shoppy/web/)

Comment: I don't follow - I'm not sure anything needed to be explained, your `toggle` variable is just initialized inversely.

Comment: you may use directly [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) with no global variable. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3q1ry4o/1/)

Comment: @gaetanoM It's perfect, but it must always be closed, it must not be open or expanded, it only expands when the user clicks the green button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to set `toggle` to `false` to start off with, as your sidebar starts off with the `sidebar-collapsed` classed, so you want to enter the `else` condition to start off with:

```js
var toggle = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".page-container").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed-back").addClass("sidebar-collapsed");
});

$(".sidebar-icon").click(function() {
  if (toggle) {
    $(".page-container").addClass("sidebar-collapsed").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
    $("#menu span").css({
      "position": "absolute"
    });
  } else {
    $(".page-container").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#menu span").css({
        "position": "relative"
      });
    }, 400);
  }
  toggle = !toggle;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/28-03-2016/shoppy/web/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/28-03-2016/shoppy/web/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/28-03-2016/shoppy/web/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-container sidebar-collapsed">
  <div class="left-content">
    <div class="mother-grid-inner">
      <!--header start here-->

      <!--heder end here-->
      <!-- /script-for sticky-nav -->
      <!--inner block start here-->
      <div class="inner-block">
        <!--market updates updates-->
        <div class="market-updates">
          <div class="col-md-4 market-update-gd">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 market-update-gd">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 market-update-gd">

          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
        <!--market updates end here-->
        <!---728x90--->
        <div style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;margin-top: 5px;"></div>
        <!--mainpage chit-chating-->
        <div class="chit-chat-layer1">
          <div class="col-md-6 chit-chat-layer1-left">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 chit-chat-layer1-rit">

          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
        <!--main page chit chating end here-->
        <!---728x90--->

        <!--main page chart start here-->
        <div class="main-page-charts">
          <div class="main-page-chart-layer1">
            <div class="col-md-6 chart-layer1-left">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 chart-layer1-right">
              <div class="user-marorm">


              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--main page chart layer2-->
        <div class="chart-layer-2">

          <div class="col-md-6 chart-layer2-right">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 chart-layer2-left">

          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>

        <!--climate start here-->
        <div class="climate">


          <div class="col-md-4 climate-grids">

          </div>

        </div>
        <!--climate end here-->
      </div>
      <!--inner block end here-->
      <!---728x90--->
      <!--COPY rights end here-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--slider menu-->
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-icon"> <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> </a>
      <a href="#"> <span id="logo"></span>
        <!--<img id="logo" src="" alt="Logo"/>-->
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li id="menu-home"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Dashboard</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Components</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="grids.html">Grids</a></li>
            <li><a href="portlet.html">Portlets</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-comunicacao"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book nav_icon"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Element</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-comunicacao-sub">
            <li id="menu-mensagens" style="width: 120px"><a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-arquivos"><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
            <li id="menu-arquivos"><a href="icons.html">Icons</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="maps.html"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Maps</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-academico"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Pages</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-academico-sub">
            <li id="menu-academico-boletim"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
            <li id="menu-academico-avaliacoes"><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="charts.html"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Charts</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span style="position: absolute;">Mailbox</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-academico-sub">
            <li id="menu-academico-avaliacoes"><a href="inbox.html">Inbox</a></li>
            <li id="menu-academico-boletim"><a href="inbox-details.html">Compose email</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span style="position: absolute;">System</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-academico-sub">
            <li id="menu-academico-avaliacoes"><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
            <li id="menu-academico-boletim"><a href="blank.html">Blank</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span style="position: absolute;">E-Commerce</span><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: right; position: absolute;"></span></a>
          <ul id="menu-academico-sub">
            <li id="menu-academico-avaliacoes"><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
            <li id="menu-academico-boletim"><a href="price.html">Price</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
```

Also note that you have duplicate IDs, which is considered **[invalid markup](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180/282231)**, and may cause issues with jQuery selectors.

Comment: Excellent, but what should I do so that it does not open automatically when it is on a small responsive screen, it must always be closed. That the only way in which the menu is expanded or open is by clicking on the green button